# How can components work concurrently in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, thread-sleep

code:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textArea_output.append(new Date() + ": start\n");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        textArea_output.append(new Date() + ": end");
    }
});
```

output:

```
Sat Nov 30 14:46:08 CST 2013: start
Sat Nov 30 14:46:13 CST 2013: end
```

The problem is that the two outputs appear at the same time. And what I want is, the first one, 5 seconds, then another.

I tried several ways to solve it but all failed. The button just froze the whole frame, even the textArea won't update its content during the time.

Answer (score 4):

Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) for repeating tasks, or a single shot `Timer` for a 'delayed effect'.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: The java docs make me frustrating, the text, the examples. I am using worker thread now, and I still don't know how to use a timer, for the sake of the example Oracle gave. Before I figure it out, and want to ask another question. When pressing that button, I will call a method which is there already and contains `Thread.sleep()` within it, will it be a problem？

Comment: And what is `blocking the EDT` and how to avoid it, I don't think I understand. I need a simple example that one toggleButton and one label. The toggleButton keeps changing the number shown on the label using worker and clock. I reckon this example will be simple forward and useful.

Comment: *"will it be a problem？"*  Yes.  *"I need a simple example"*  I need a pony.  If you want more help, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best effort.

Comment: Dude I was not trying to be rude or greedy. Just if you can have a look at the `TumbleItem` example and should understand how I feel.

Comment: *"understand how I feel"*  Are you *kidding?*  This is a technical forum, not a social site.    *"Just if you can have a look at the.."*  Just if you can actually *read* the SSCCE document and add one.  You expect me to help you when you ignore my advice?

Answer (score 0):

This [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453206/java-swing-concurrency-display-jtextarea) helps. Just Simply starts a new Thread. (I tried this but I don't know why it didn't work that time.